# LED's won't light up with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

This is the code I have in Arduino:

```
int blue1 = 1;
int blue2 = 2;
int blue3 = 3;
int blue4 = 4;

int yell1 = 5;
int yell2 = 6;
int yell3 = 7;
int yell4 = 8;

int red1 = 9;
int red2 = 10;
int red3 = 11;
int red4 = 12;

int knob = A0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(blue1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(blue2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(blue3,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(blue4,OUTPUT);

  pinMode(yell1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(yell2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(yell3,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(yell4,OUTPUT);

  pinMode(red1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(red2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(red3,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(red4,OUTPUT);

  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);

  pinMode(knob,INPUT);  //Value from potentiometer

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  delay(250);

  digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
  delay(250);
  digitalWrite(13,LOW);

  int number = analogRead(knob);  //'number' is return from potentiometer
  Serial.println(number);

  digitalWrite(blue1,HIGH);

  if(number > 85) {
    digitalWrite(blue1,HIGH);
  }
  if(number > 170) {
    digitalWrite(blue2,HIGH);
  }
  if(number > 255) {
   digitalWrite(blue3,HIGH);
  }
  if(number > 340) {
    digitalWrite(blue4,HIGH);
  }
  if(number > 425) {
    digitalWrite(yell1,HIGH);
  }
  if(number > 510) {
    digitalWrite(yell2,HIGH);
  }
  if(number > 595) {
    digitalWrite(yell3,HIGH);
  }
  if(number > 680) {
    digitalWrite(yell4,HIGH);
  }
  if(number > 765) {
    digitalWrite(red1,HIGH);
  }
  if(number > 850) {
    digitalWrite(red2,HIGH);
  }
  if(number > 935) {
    digitalWrite(red3,HIGH);
  }
  if(number == 1023) {
    digitalWrite(red4,HIGH);
  }                     
}
```

The goal is to have a strip of LED's that lights up, and the higher the return value from the potentiometer, the more LED's light up.  I know the potentiometer is working fine, because it's printing values to the Serial window.  And  I'm almost certain I have the wiring right on the breadboard.  So basically I'm here to verify that the CODE is fine.  I can't really get a good picture of the breadboard(and 'm not even sure how to post it if I could).  So, if you find any problems in the code, please let me know(and how to fix them, please).  but if you can't, then I'll know he problem is with the breadboard itself, or with the way I wired things.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two main problems with your code:

1. You are using `Serial`, although you are reserving **pin** `1` for your strip of led. You can't have both ways: either you use the **pin** for the *Serial* interface (which, by default, uses pins `0` and `1`), or you use the pin for the *led*. Trying to do both things can damage your component and/or your device. *Thus, you should remove all the code referring to the Serial interface.*
2. You do not set any **pin** to `LOW` state, which means that if **number** is equal to `1023` in one loop, after that moment every pin will be on `HIGH` forever. You should set every pin back to `LOW` either at the beginning of the loop, or by adding an **else** branch for each `if` condition.

Other than that, since you are using so many pins then I would advice you to check that the current absorbed by your device does not exceed the  **Arduino**'s [current limitations](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/ArduinoPinCurrentLimitations), as you could damage your board.